# How to fit image and text into vieport in CSS 2?

Tags: html, css

I need an image and its text description beneath to fit into viewport, by scaling an image. I'm targeting old devices, so it should be done in CSS 2. None of the existing solutions seems to be working, not for what I need to achieve at least.

Here is what I tried so far and it doesn't seem to work.

```
div.full-page {
    max-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div.full-page img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

p.caption {
    text-indent: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```
<div class="full-page">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/01/25/08/55/apple-iphone-12-pro-max-5947688_1280.png"/>
<p class="caption">Caption</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use vw. vh units? it's available since 2015

Comment: Are they available in CSS 2? If so, then yes. I'm targeting old devices that don't support anything after CSS 2.

Comment: I think you will need to look at the CSS2 spec - but even then some browsers may have bugs. (I can't see vw in the spec but may have just missed it). Would it be possible to know which versions of which browsers you need to target? using caniuse.com then makes things simpler.

Comment: I don't know exact browsers. Just being CSS 2 compatible would be enough for me.